# How to use my agent to enter a process flow of a specific agent (ex: Depot[0]) from a population of agent (ex: Depots)?

Tags: anylogic

So, I have a case in anylogic where a drone needs to be transported via a bike from a certain place (namely, Depot) to a certain place (namely, Stopover Point). After that, the drone will be released from the bike and will do some mapping to a set of designated locations of Mapping Points. For this case, I used a process flow to make the bike (that I treat as a resource unit) to seize the agent (drone) at the Depot before the bike move to the Stopover Point and releasing the drone there.

At first, I used to make some kind of sandbox model where I only use one Depot and one Stopover Point
so that it is easier when I want to use my agent (drone) in a process flow via enter block (ex: I only have to write `main.depot.enter.take(this);` at my agent (drone) statechart to enter it to the process flow at Depot bacause the Depot is a single agent).

The problem occurs when I tried to use more than one Depot and make it as a population of agent. This makes me unable to use `main.depot.enter.take(this);` because of the property of the Depot for it is now a population of agent and not a single agent anymore.

The question is how should I do if I want my agent (drone) to enter the process flow of a certain/specific Depot (ex: only Depot[0])? I have used a paramater such as "name" with the value consists of texts like "Depot 1, Depot 2, and so on" and modify the commmand to `filter(main.depots, a -> a.name == "Depot 1").enter.take(this);` or `main.depot[0].enter.take(this);` but I think that's not the right way to code it because it didn't works. So, how is exactly the correct way to code or to do it if I want my agent to enter a process flow of a specific agent (ex: Depot[0]) from a population of agent (ex: Depots)? Thank you.

Comment: "because it didn't works" -> what did not work? Please clarify the core question, it is very long for a very short actual issue. Your code looks fine, tbh. See here for some tips on good SOF questions: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You should use () instead of [] to select one depot from the population.
So to select the one with index 0, you write: `main.depot(0).enter.take(this)`.

To select a depot based on the `name` parameter, I would use the findFirst function which selects one of the depots. In your exitblock, you could write:

```
main.depot(findFirst(main.depot, a->a.name.equals("Depot1")).getIndex()).enter.take(this)
```

The `getIndex()`method returns the index of the selected agent.